# What g++ link option to fix the error function not found

Tags: c++

My project uses g++ compiler to compile the source code distributed over several directories, finally an executable is built. But in building the final executable I get link error function not defined.

I cooked the following code which is a scaled down of my project and exposes the same error, hope you could help me out.

So here is the directory tree and the source files:

```
./

./11/
c1.cpp  c1.h

./12/
c2.cpp
```

Here are the files:

```
./11/c1.h:
int f();

./11/c1.cpp:
#include "c1.h"

int f()
{
    return 0;
}

./12/c2.cpp:
#include "c1.h"

int main()
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the steps I build the files:

```
cd 11
g++ -c -o ../c1.o c1.cpp
cp c1.h ..
cd ..
ar cr libc1.a c1.o
cd 12
g++  -I../ -L../ -lc1 c2.cpp
```

Yes, I need to compile c1 to object and archive it even it is small, but this is how my project is doing.

And here is the error message:

```
/tmp/cctFdZLe.o: In function `main':
c2.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `f()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks!

Comment: Place the linker library after the source file in the last command line, so do e.g. `g++ -I.. c2.cpp -L.. -lc1` Dependencies need to come after the source/object/library that depends in it on the command line.

Comment: Yes, Joachim is right.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Post that as an answer